# Undefined reference to error

Tags: c++

My program must compute the smallest floating point number my computer can represent. However, I keep getting this error when I try to compile:

> [Linker error] undefined reference to `WinMain@16'
>         ld returned 1 exit status

Here is my code so far..

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

#include <math.h>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

float smallest()
{
  float x=1.0;
  while(1) {
    if((x / 2) == 0.0) {
      return x;
    }
    x = x / 2;
    cout << "Approx smallest" << x << "float:" <<  endl;
  }
system("PAUSE");
return(x);
}
```

As I am new to C++, can I assume this is an error relating to my main file - or my lack of one?

Comment: Look up just about any "first C++ program" tutorial.

Comment: Would "negative infinity" meet your needs?

Comment: -1 for having put **absolutely no effort** in learning.

Answer (score 4):

`main()` function is the entry point of any C++ program running in hosted environment. Your program is missing a main function.

Seems you are trying to create a Windows UI appplication, So you need to define a:
**[WinMain entry point (Windows)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633559%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)**

Comment: `WinMain` isn't necessary, even with a Windows subsystem. I use `main()` with Windows projects etc. all the time, despite GCC being a bit less hostile about it than MSVC.

Comment: @chris: Because every implementation **must** support two standard versions of `main()` while implementation can provide its own function signatures. But it makes sense that *"when in Rome act like the romans do"*. Check section 3.6.1 if it interests you more.

Comment: I agree it's the general consensus for Windows Apps, but I'm just saying it isn't mandatory, and MSVC is nonstandard to complain when you use `main` instead of `WinMain`. Often times I don't need or want the info passed in through it.

Comment: @chris: It's not mandatory because every implementation has to support the two standard mandated main versions.

Comment: Agreed. The implementation must support those two, so why should it complain when you use one of them?

Comment: @chris: It shouldn't. It will not. OP didn't define any `main` at all and hence the linking error.

Comment: The reason I spiralled off was because of the wording: *So you* ***need*** *to define a WinMain entry point*. The sad fact of the matter is that with default settings, a Win32 GUI project in MSVS will complain when your whole program is `int main(){}` because it expects `WinMain`. That's a common cause for misconception that you need `WinMain` when using Windows projects, so I jumped to a couple of conclusions there.

Comment: @chris: **need** to yes, not **must** a simple `main()` will do too. I suggested `WinMain()` because as i said *"when in Rome act like the romans do"*. Anyhow I understand the confusion due to subtle words :)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to compile it as an executable, and you don't have a [`main` function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_function):

```
// your code 

int main()
{
  smalltest(); // call your function
}
```